# Docker with Spring Boot - cannot connect to external servers

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

Experienced C# developer, new to Spring Boot and even newer to Docker.

While trying to leverage Kafka and Kafka Streams, I wrote my solution in Spring Boot which involves connecting to a network Oracle database and a network Kafka server cluster.  My solution works great and does all I want it to using the connections inside the Java application.properties file inside Spring Boot.  Great.

Kafka and Oracle servers are on the same domain.  Like OracleServer.companydomain.com and KafkaServer.companydomian.com.

I then moved to port the solution to Docker so that I can deploy it on our production Windows servers.  I started by adding it to Docker in layers.  First a hello world, then I added the Oracle connection without Kafka.  Both worked.  Great.

Then I added Kafka.  Started to not work.  I've tried KafkaServer, KafkaServer.companydomain.com, and even the IP address for KafkaServer.  All gave same error.

java.net.UnknownHostException: KafkaServer

Funny, if I use server name, full domain server name, or IP address, message is same.  Somehow it was translated from IP address to server name even though it won't connect.

I started Docker container without Kafka, and inside the container terminal I was able to ping the IP address as well as KafkaServer.companydomain.com.

I tried adding a MongoDB server that is on a different network that is MongoServer.companydomain2.com and it also didn't work with similar messages.

I tried putting connections in the docker-compose file and got the same issues.

I'm confused as to why I can connect to Oracle with zero issues inside Docker, but not to Kafka or MongoDB.

```
#application.properties
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//OracleServer.companydomain.com:1522/oracleRW.companydomain.com
spring.datasource.username = user_id
spring.datasource.password = pwd

spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers = KafkaServer1.companydomain.com:9092, KafkaServer2.companydomain.com:9092, KafkaServer3.companydomain.com:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = group_id
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset = earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers = KafkaServer1.companydomain.com:9092, KafkaServer2.companydomain.com:9092, KafkaServer2.companydomain.com:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://MongoServer1:27017,MongoServer2:27017,MongoServer3:27017/?replicaSet=MongoReplica&readPreference=primary&ssl=false
spring.data.mongodb.database=MyMongoDbDatabase
```

```
#docker-compose.yml
services:
  spring-boot:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8079:8079
    environment:
      - spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers = KafkaServer1.companydomain.com:9092, KafkaServer2.companydomain.com:9092, KafkaServer3.companydomain.com:9092
      - spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = group_id
      - spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset = earliest
      - spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      - spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      - spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers = KafkaServer1.companydomain.com:9092, KafkaServer2.companydomain.com:9092, KafkaServer3.companydomain.com:9092
      - spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      - spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

```
#Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-alpine3.12
EXPOSE 8079
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/MyAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} myApi.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","myApi.jar"]
```

Comment: 1. The spring config values with periods aren't valid environment variables 2. Your servers need to tell the clients how to connect. It's still possible to get DNS errors without fixing this https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/ ; for Mongo you'll need to speak with your networking team